# How can I return value names (Alive, Dead) instead of returning 1 and 0

Tags: python

I have made this function to return the cells that are dead and alive in the rows of the game of life. Instead of returning 0 for dead and 1 for alive, how can just return dead, alive

This is an example of what I can currently run:
**

```
0 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1 0
```

**

```
def update_game_board(input_board):

    alive = 1
    dead = 0
    row = 0

    ##Loops through 
    for row in range(0,input_board.shape[0]):
        print("**")
        for index in range(0,input_board.shape[1]):
            print(input_board[row][index])
            index = index + 1

    return np.logical_not(input_board)*1
```

Comment: Have a look at Python's enum module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: I mean if you want a string I can see the answers pouring in now but you have left the return type that you want ambigious

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python how to get name of the enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446945/python-how-to-get-name-of-the-enum)

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict:

```
value = {0: 'Dead', 1: 'Alive'}
def update_game_board(input_board):

    alive = 1
    dead = 0
    row = 0

    ##Loops through 
    for row in range(0,input_board.shape[0]):
        print("**")
        for index in range(0,input_board.shape[1]):
            print(input_board[row][index])
            index = index + 1

    return value[np.logical_not(input_board)*1]
```

Comment: It would be easier just to make a list: `['Dead', 'Alive']`.

Comment: A dict follow the rule: "Explicit is better than implicit." 

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: I am using numpy in the other functions, so I get the error unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'.

Answer (score 1):

use a dictionary that maps the integer values to the desired strings?

```
output = {1: "alive", 0: "dead"}

...

    print(output[input_board[row][index]])
```

Comment: I am using numpy in the other functions, so I get the error unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when I use a dictionary

Comment: How are you trying to implement this?  It should not be a matter of NumPy for the references people have given you.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a list using `l = ['dead', 'alive']`. Then, at the last line, instead of using `return np.logical_not(input_board)*1`, use `return l[np.logical_not(input_board)*1]`.

Comment: I don't think I can return the list string indices while using Numpy. I get the the error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed your main program, so we're not entire certain how you've implemented the board.  I've designed this to solve the problem I *think* you're having with linking everything together.  This is merely the conversion from 0/1 to "dead ", "alive" (5 chars each for consistency) in the main program; the functional logic is yours to play with.

```
board = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
])

# Make a conversion table.
# Instantiate it as a lambda function,
#   and vectorize that to support arrays.
life_status = {0: "dead ", 1:"alive"}
life_text = lambda c: life_status[c]
vect_life = np.vectorize(life_text)

print("\nGENERATION 0:")
print(vect_life(board))

next_gen = update_game_board(board)
print("\nGENERATION 1:")
print(vect_life(next_gen))
```

Output:

```
GENERATION 0:
[['dead ' 'dead ' 'alive' 'dead ' 'alive' 'alive']
 ['dead ' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'alive']
 ['dead ' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'alive' 'alive']
 ['alive' 'alive' 'dead ' 'alive' 'alive' 'alive']
 ['dead ' 'dead ' 'alive' 'alive' 'dead ' 'alive']
 ['dead ' 'dead ' 'alive' 'alive' 'alive' 'dead ']]

GENERATION 1:
[['alive' 'alive' 'dead ' 'alive' 'dead ' 'dead ']
 ['alive' 'alive' 'alive' 'alive' 'alive' 'dead ']
 ['alive' 'alive' 'alive' 'alive' 'dead ' 'dead ']
 ['dead ' 'dead ' 'alive' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'dead ']
 ['alive' 'alive' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'alive' 'dead ']
 ['alive' 'alive' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'dead ' 'alive']]
```

These results are somewhat anti-climactic, since your `update` merely negates every cell, but I trust you'll complicate that properly when you get past this part.  :-)